# generate a random unique code in php and create a table and store it in a table in Mysql

Tags: php

I need help to generate a random unique code in php and create a table and store it in a table in Mysql ,then give this random numbers to anyone who wants to register  after which registration will be successful for those that used the random generated number and unsuccessful for those who didn't use the random number

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7, it's easy to generate a random string:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(5); //random. Increase input for more bytes
$code = bin2hex($bytes); // eg: 385e33f741
```

Before PHP 7, I would generate an alphanumeric code with a function

```
function getRandomString($length){
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';    
    $result = '';
    while(strlen($result)<$length):
        $result .= $chars{mt_rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)};
    endwhile;
    return $result;
}
```

To get a 10-character random code, you just call:

```
$code = getRandomString(10);
```

You can add more characters to `$chars`, such as capital letters and punctuations if you want those in the generated code

Answer (score 0):

this function should do the trick

```
function random_Id($length = 6) {
        $id = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
return $id;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution in my opinion.  Randomness is reduced with every additional character because the function will use each character only once.